# Need to change my status bar color to white

Tags: ios

I'm doing my first iOS project. I need to change my status bar color from default black to white. I know how to add a file in my `info.plist`, 
`View Controller-based Status bar appearance` to `No`.

But still I am not getting my white color. Did I forgot any code to add? Kindly, give me some assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you post some question please check many question are there like your problems.
This is quit simple.You need to add below line to your `"AppDelegate.m"`

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

Thats it !!Hope this helpful

Comment: Thanks for your replay.will check out

Comment: Sorry I am new to ios . So only if I see any solution also can't verify that answer. And thanks it's work.Thank a lot

Comment: This helps me.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Go to your general tab.under in `deployment tab` select your status bar style to `light`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the below function to the initial viewcontroller

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle) preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for yur replay.Will also check this answer